# Hover on a single line of TEXT (not LINK)

Tags: css, text

I am trying to make a kind of box in which text is aligned both to the left and right and when I hover over a line, I want it to become another color.

My question is: How do I do that with CSS, is it even possible to accomplish?
I have low skills in coding and I can't figure it out. So I got the text to align correctly but this is where I'm stuck.

HTML

```
<div class="border">
<h3 class="text">I want these lines to separately<span>become red when hovering.</span></h3>
<p class="text">Not all<span>of them at the same time.</span></p>
<p class="text">Can you <span>please help?</span></p>
<p class="text">That would be much appreciated, <span>thank you!</span></p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.border {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin:10px;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

:hover .text {
  color: red;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.text span {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

This is what I've got so far.  As you can see, all of the lines become red...

ANY help is much appreciated!
http://jsfiddle.net/4m4bcvm9/

Comment: Im sorry but I did not get the line `:hover .text ` what does it mean? is it a mistyping?

Comment: Hi there Advokaten, please don't reply to this thread for your question updates. Instead, edit the question.

Comment: Sorry @ManojKumar, still don't quite know how to use this site.

Comment: Not a problem at all. You can delete your answers and make them as an edit. People will answer to your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
:hover .text {
    color: red;
    transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

to

```
.text:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

I would also suggest you change the 5s to a shorter time, as one have difficult to see it if one move the mouse to fast over the text

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with your css file. the correct one is here:

```
.border {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: thin;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin:10px;
}

.text {
display: block;
  text-align: center;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.text:hover {
color: red;

}

.text span {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

and another thing is that, putting `transition` in the part that does not have *pseudo class* (i mean `:hover`) is a better approach as far as I know and this is where you see it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This fix works for me, change:

```
:hover .text {
    color: red;
    transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

to

```
.border .text:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is relevant but I tried doing it offline in a .css and .html file using Brackets and I got it working.
I tried uploading the stylesheet. I'm using this:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <body>
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="behandlingstyle.css">
    </head>
    <div class="border">
   <h3 class="text">I want these lines to separately<span>become red when hovering.</span></h3>
   <p class="text">Not all<span>of them at the same time.</span></p>
   <p class="text">Can you <span>please help?</span></p>
   <p class="text">That would be much appreciated, <span>thank you!</span></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The CSS is not loading, how does one fix that? 
The css styling doesn't load editing the wordpress theme style.css file either, just to clarify!

Again, any help is MUCH appreciated! Thank you!

**Edit**:

I FINALLY got it working thanks to my brutal coding skills...
I created a new css file and added the href link, and voila! It worked, I can't tell you how amazed I am over this.
This is what fixed my problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ultra/newstyle.css">
```

And the .css loaded correctly.

Thank you all for your responses :)